# matrix row merge in R

Tags: r, matrix, unique

I have a matrix

```
     [,1]   [,2]
 [1,]   2     3
 [2,]   3     5
 [3,]   7     9
 [4,]   11    3
 [5,]   11    8
```

and I want to merge row 1 2 4 5 by their common value.

the result should be output

```
  2 3 5 11 8
```

Comment: That is not a correct use of the word "merge" when used in the R sense or the database sense. You appear to be asking for a set operation. There is also a complementary indexing function: `duplicated` return a logical vector and is often used with a prefixed `!` to return a vector for selection of unique elements.

Answer (score 1):

Test case:

```
m <- matrix(c(2,3,7,11,11,3,5,9,3,8),ncol=2)
```

I'm not *sure* this is what you want, but it gives the right answer:

```
unique(c(t(m[c(1,2,4,5),])))
```

Only two tricky bits here:

- need to use `c()` to collapse the matrix into a single vector
- need to use `t()` to get the matrix collapsed row-wise rather than column-wise to get the ordering as you specified.